# Assign value from next cell that is in between blank cells

Tags: excel

Essentially, I have a very long column that goes something like this

```
A
[blank]
1
2
3
2
5
[blank]
B
[blank]
4
2
5
3
2
[blank]
C
[blank]
9
[blank]
D
```

Where A, B, C etc are names of "locations" in which "items" (numbers) are stored. Those locations are displayed at the end of the "item" list within that location. What I need is a formula that could be ran across the list and in a separate column return the following result:

```
A
[blank]
1 B
2 B
3 B
2 B
5 B
[blank]
B
[blank]
4 C
2 C
5 C
3 C
2 C
[blank]
C
[blank]
9 D
[blank]
D
```

Tried just about anything with only marginal results. Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried a few variations of `IF`

```
=IF(AND(B1="",B3=""),B2,"")
```

then I got a little more elaborate

```
=IF(B:B<>"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MIN((B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B))),COLUMN(B:B))))
```

but the problem is that I don't need either the `MIN(first)` or the `MAX(last)`, just the next "location" between two blanks

Comment: I have a solution, but let's see what you have attempted first. Edit your question to include whatever your most successful formula(s) are and we can work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is from Cell **`A1`** to **`A18`**, here is the formula which is working for me based on your test data:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1),"",
CONCATENATE(IF(ISTEXT(A1),"",
IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1))," ",
IF(AND(A2="",A4=""),
IF(OR(ISNUMBER(A3),A3=""),"",A3),
IF(A1="","",B2)
)
)
)
```

This formula is using combination of **`IF, ISTEXT, ISBLANK, AND, OR, ISNUMBER`**.
Just place this formula in Cell **`B1`** and drag it down till you have data in column **`A`**.

- **Based on comment and updated question**:

If you just need A, B, C, etc. in let's say column B, than place following formula in Cell B1 and drag it down. I have enhanced Forward Ed's formula.

```
=IF(AND(A2="",A4=""),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(A3),A3=""),"",A3),IF(A1="","",B2))
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: WOW! I would have never even imagined such an approach. it does work on test data, however, I do not need concatenation to be involved. only for A,B,C etc appear alongside 1,2,3,4,5 etc in a separate column.

Comment: Thank you so much for the revision, however, it throws a #VALUE! error in all column B cells except for the last number in each location                                                                                                            A
    [blank]
    1 #VALUE!
    2 #VALUE!
    3 #VALUE!
    2 #VALUE!
    5 B
    [blank]
    B
    [blank]
    4 #VALUE!
    2 #VALUE!
    5 #VALUE!
    3 #VALUE!
    2 C
    [blank]
    C
    [blank]
    9 D
    [blank]
    D

Comment: The directions are pretty straight forward and I double checked everything, but so far this is what im looking at. Not sure what the problem is on my end...nonetheless, thank you for your input and additional suggestions https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9wUJ0NbmUBeMkxaQzBUOC03cnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try the latest formula that I've updated in my answer and let me know.

Comment: GENIOUS! now all I need to figure out is how to apply it to the actual list. thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. If you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer, other will know you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will pull the trailing address up and put it in the cell adjacent to the number.  However if you need the number and the trailing address in the same cell then the formula will need to be modified with a concatenation.

```
=IF(AND(A2="",A4=""),A3,IF(A1="","",B2))
```

Put that in the column beside A, assuming A is in cell A1, and copy down.

Comment: thank you for your reply. it works on my simplified example, but unfortunately when I add it into the actual list, it only duplicates the numbers within the location instead of the location

Comment: @scott Is there a gap between two of the numbers within the same location? Otherwise this seems to work. Modify your example data to represent an instance where this code fails in your actual data.

Comment: @Scott I second what tittaenalg said, we need to see how your sample data varies from you actual data in order to adjust the formula.  Are some of the cells that you are claiming are blank, have spaces in them so they appear visually to be blank, but actually they are not?

Comment: the problem really is that the very first "location" (A)  has 197 items (numbers) in it, so the IF does not look far enough ahead to return location value (A)

Comment: The formula I provided, does not care how many items are under A.  What it cares about is there is a space after A, then the label B, then a space after the label B.   Its the space label space pattern that triggers the label pull.  if those space are not in that pattern or those spaces have an actual " " space in them, then the formula will not work.

Comment: also you cant have a single space/blank in your 197 rows apparently after the data  after A starts.

Comment: @Forwarded my apologies, indeed after tinkering with your suggestion a little bit, it almost works for it all except for rare instances that go like this C[blank]3[blank]D[blank]. in these cases, the formula returns a 3 and a D (not in the same cell obviously)

Comment: Scott, update your question to reflect this change in pattern